# Python tkinter Canvas Image Not Visible, Only Visible When Forced Error

Tags: python, tkinter

I have code that will place an image down, if the image path exists, if the image path does not exist, then it will be a default as "False", using a simple if statement, if image_path:
then it will place the image. However I have defined the 2 images, and then when the if statements run, it runs the code, printing that it has placed the image, but the image is not visible. For some reason though, when I don't define the second image, it will return as an error, but before the error is displayed, the first image is successfully placed.

```
    homeIconPath = "path to image"
    awayIconPath = False
```

When awayIconPath is not defined (If I comment it out) The code gives an error, but it places the image

```
            imagePosLeft = [75, 100, 100]
            imagePosRight = [425, 100, 100]
```

```
            if homeIconPath:
                if side == "left":
                    print(f"Placed Home Image On Left Side with path: {homeIconPath}")
                    img1 = resize_image(homeIconPath, imagePosLeft[2], imagePosLeft[2])
                    homeIconImage = canvas.create_image(imagePosLeft[0], imagePosLeft[1], anchor=tk.CENTER, image=img1)
                else:
                    print(f"Placed Home Image On Right Side with path: {homeIconPath}")
                    img2 = resize_image(homeIconPath, imagePosRight[2], imagePosRight[2])
                    homeIconImage = canvas.create_image(imagePosRight[0], imagePosRight[1], anchor=tk.CENTER, image=img2)

            if awayIconPath:
                if side == "left":
                    print(f"Placed Away Image On Right Side with path: {awayIconPath}")
                    img3 = resize_image(awayIconPath, imagePosRight[2], imagePosRight[2])
                    awayIconImage = canvas.create_image(imagePosRight[0], imagePosRight[1], anchor=tk.CENTER, image=img3)
                else:
                    print(f"Placed Away Image On Left Side with path: {awayIconPath}")
                    img4 = resize_image(awayIconPath, imagePosLeft[2], imagePosLeft[2])
                    awayIconImage = canvas.create_image(imagePosLeft[0], imagePosLeft[1], anchor=tk.CENTER, image=img4)
```

Here is the complete code for reference:
h`ttps://docs.google.com/document/d/1RMkNonyR2egVcoygp20GrBDmmj55-JVJ4-AMhQcz25Y/edit?usp=sharing`

I have tried many things and it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is very simple : `homeIconPath` is False.

see `handelGraphics`'s definition :

```py
def handelGraphics(timer, timerValuestr, possession, switch, team1, team2, coloredSides, homeIcon, awayIcon, hasPeriod):
    global switchPossible, currentPos, timerBase, keybinds, toggle_fullscreen, update_scores, period, periodPossible, team1Name, team2Name, awayIconPath, homeIconPath
    global root, colorLeft, colorRight, left, right, score_labelL, score_labelR, scoreL, scoreR, side, timerValue, paused, timerText, possessionPossible
    global leftName, rightName, currentPos, posText, awayIconImage, homeIconImage
    timerValue = timerValuestr
    homeIconPath = homeIcon #You set homeIconPath to homeIcon, let's see its value.
    #...
```

See now your call to this function :

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    handelGraphics(True, '04:13', True, 'switch', 'Home', 'Away', False, False, False, True) 
# You set homeIcon to False.
```

Good luck for the future !

Comment: I'm not calling it through there, I am calling it in a different file